# Set long tooltip text in html through javascript

Tags: jquery, html, json, tooltip

I was thinking about how to set `title` on some `div` who has a really long text showed in a tooltip. 
Right now I am replacing this long text binding `div` with `id`s or `class`s and then

```
$("#id").attr("title", "really really long text...");
```

Because I'm avoiding to set the `title` attribute with such a long text , it would be bad and not clear.

But, the solution I adopted right now, oblige me to set it individually for every `div` and have tons of line of code with the same syntax but for different `div`.

There's a way to replace `title`s in html , through a loop and with the help of , for example, `data-*` bindings or template-like syntax , e.g. `{{text-for-this-ttip}}` ,obviusly retrieved from a `JSON` object ? I imagine something like

```
<div id="someid" title={{object-name}}></div>
```

hope I've been clearly explained. cheers.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If there's a way to replace div's title better than the mine.

Comment: div has title attribute ? instead you can use your div content(text) by cutting some text from it and show it in your tooltip area. 

Regards